# PHP: header() function not redirecting. When redirecting with HTML or JavaScript, Session information is lost

Tags: php, javascript, apache, redirect, http-redirect

This is a PHP/Apache question...

1. I have the following code. In particular I would like to emphasize the
   following:

   ```
         // store email in session variable

         $_SESSION["jobseeker_email"] = $_POST["jobseeker_email"];

         // perform redirect

         $target = util_siblingurl("jobseekermain.php", true);

         header("Location: " . $target);

         exit; /* ensure code below does not executed when we redirect */
   ```

which is where the problem lies. When I execute this code on localhost it works fine,
but then when I execute it on the remote server (which is an ipage.com hosted site), I
do not get the desired outcome. In fact, when the header("Location: $target); part runs
I see a blank page (and no redirect). It's as though something was being output before
the call to header(), but this is not the case, as I've checked it. So why is it not
working?

1. If I comment out the part that invokes header() and then exit, I am able to
   perform either an html redirect or a javascript redirect. However, when I do this
   I lose my session variable $_SESSION["jobseeker_email"]. I cannot understand why
   this happens.

Any help with these issues would be greatly appreciated as I need to perform a redirect
and still retain the session state from the former page, and all of this on a server
(not just on localhost).

```
    <?php

      session_start();

      require_once('include/connect.php');
      require_once('include/util.php');

      util_ensure_secure();

      if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {

        session_destroy();

        // restart session

        header("Location: " . util_selfurl(true));

      }

      function do_match_passwords($password1, $password2) {

        return strcmp($password1, $password2) == 0;

      }

      function valid_employer_login($email, $password) {

        global $mysqli;

        global $employer_error;

        $query = "SELECT passwd FROM Employer WHERE email = '" . $mysqli->escape_string($email) . "'";

        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        util_check_query_result($query, $result);

        $invalid_credentials = false;

        if ($result->num_rows == 0) {

          $invalid_credentials = true;

        } else {

          $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

          $retrieved_password = $row["passwd"];

          if (!do_match_passwords($password, $retrieved_password))

        $invalid_credentials = true;

        }

        if ($invalid_credentials) {

          $employer_error = "Invalid credentials.";

          return false;

        }

        return true;

      }

      function valid_jobseeker_login($email, $password) {

        global $mysqli;

        global $jobseeker_error;

        $query = "SELECT passwd FROM JobSeeker WHERE email = '" . $mysqli->escape_string($email) . "'";

        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        util_check_query_result($query, $result);

        $invalid_credentials = false;

        if ($result->num_rows == 0) {

          $invalid_credentials = true;

        } else {

          $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

          $retrieved_password = $row["passwd"];

          if (!do_match_passwords($password, $retrieved_password))

        $invalid_credentials = true;

        }

        if ($invalid_credentials) {

          $jobseeker_error = "Invalid credentials.";

          return false;

        }

        return true;

      }

      if (isset($_POST["employer_submitted"])) {

        global $error;

        // check whether specified username and password have been entered correctly

        if (valid_employer_login($_POST["employer_email"], $_POST["employer_password"])) {

          // store email in session variable

          $_SESSION["employer_email"] = $_POST["employer_email"];

          // perform redirect

          $target = util_siblingurl("jobseekermain.php", true);

          header("Location: " . $target);

          exit; /* ensure code below does not executed when we redirect */

        }

      }

      if (isset($_POST["jobseeker_submitted"])) {

        global $error;

        // check whether specified username and password have been entered correctly

        if (valid_jobseeker_login($_POST["jobseeker_email"], $_POST["jobseeker_password"])) {

          // store email in session variable

          $_SESSION["jobseeker_email"] = $_POST["jobseeker_email"];

          // perform redirect

          $target = util_siblingurl("jobseekermain.php", true);

          header("Location: " . $target);

          exit; /* ensure code below does not executed when we redirect */

        }

      }

    ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Work Net: Sign In</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="container">
          <h1>Work Net: Sign In</h1>
          <div id="content">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h2>Employers</h2>
            <p><a href="accountcreate.php?accounttype=employer">Create new employer account.</a></p>
            <form method="post" action="<?php util_selfurl(true); ?>">
              <table>
            <tr>
              <td>E-mail:</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="employer_email" value="<?= htmlentities(util_setvalueorblank($_POST['employer_email'])); ?>" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Password:</td>
              <td><input type="password" name="employer_password" value="<?= htmlentities(util_setvalueorblank($_POST['employer_password'])); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
              </table>
              <?php if (isset($employer_error)) echo "<p style=\"color: red;\">" . htmlentities($employer_error) . "</p>"; ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="employer_submitted" />
              <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
            </form>
            <p><a href="forgottenpassword.php?accounttype=employer">Forgotten Employer Password.</a></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h2>Job Seekers</h2>
            <p><a href="accountcreate.php?accounttype=jobseeker">Create new job seeker account.</a></p>
            <form method="post" action="<?php util_selfurl(true); ?>">
              <table>
            <tr>
              <td>E-mail:</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="jobseeker_email" value="<?= htmlentities(util_setvalueorblank($_POST['jobseeker_email'])); ?>" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Password:</td>
              <td><input type="password" name="jobseeker_password" value="<?= htmlentities(util_setvalueorblank($_POST['jobseeker_password'])); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
              </table>
              <?php if (isset($jobseeker_error)) echo "<p style=\"color: red;\">" . htmlentities($jobseeker_error) . "</p>"; ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="jobseeker_submitted" />
              <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
            </form>
            <p><a href="forgottenpassword.php?accounttype=jobseeker">Forgotten Job Seeker Password.</a></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="footer">
        <p>
          <?php include('markup/footer.php'); ?>
        </p>
          </div><!-- end #footer -->
        </div><!-- end #container -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sounds like the UTF8-BOM issue. How are you sure there is no output before the header, what headers do you receive?

Comment: when you see a blank page and no redirect what is the content of the response from the server?

Comment: can you show the output of   var_dump(util_siblingurl("jobseekermain.php", true) );

Comment: The output of var_dump is: string(59) "http://timescapezonecom.ipage.com/worknet/jobseekermain.php" (which differs from the code I posted which is in a file called http://timescapezonecom.ipage.com/worknet/login.php).

Comment: @JohnGoche Have you enabled error reporting?

Comment: Yes, I've placed error_reporting(E_ALL); just before the first line of code which is session_start(); . I still just get a blank page and that's it, with no redirection, and no error messages. Just a one whitespace byte at the most whose origin I cannot track down.

Comment: Have you also added `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`?

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing the code for util_siblingurl() my guess would be that your problem is a pathing issue. The combination of your util_siblingurl() function and Apache settings could be causing inconsistent pathing.

For example, on localhost you may be redirected to http://example.com/some/path/to/jobseekermain.php and on the remote host you may be redirected to http://example.com/some/different/path/to/jobseekermain.php

The fact that you're seeing a white screen and not a 404 causes me some hesitation in this hypothesis but it would still be helpful to see the code for that function.

Comment: The fact that OP sees a white screen is because he probably doesn't have error reporting enabled (like he should).

Comment: OK, I have added the ini_set('display_errors', 1); and get the following: 0
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: The web server is ipage.com, presumably the most notorious web hosting service on the web. How can it be outputting this? A server problem which is not a code problem? What's going on? I have contacted the staff there but they told me "it's a coding problem, contact a webmaster". Huh, anyone have an idea of what the problem could be in concrete terms?

Comment: That looks like a 500 error that could be caused by a fatal PHP error which occurs before any output can be sent. Do you have access to Apache error logs?

Comment: Actually, including just about any file prior to calling header() will cause an error, what a bummer, it's as though there is some space at the end of the file causing the problem. It might even get added after the upload to the server since on the local machine I don't see the problem.

Comment: This sounds like a BOM problem (mentioned above by Bergi).
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

To fix this you will need to use an editor that allows you to remove the BOM. Notepad++ has this ability and I'm sure others do as well.

Comment: No, when I view my output with curl I can just see an ASCII 0 (zero) character before the doctype. No idea where it's coming from, but I've gone through the Wikipedia Byte-Order-Mark and have Notepad++ installed but don't see any reference to that zero character.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do 2 things to find out what the problem is:

1. Use Wireshark. See exactly what headers you receive. This may tell you exactly what causes the problem (maybe the hosting always prints something at the top of the page, like some free hostings do?)
2. Check if other header redirections work. Create a php script which simply does the redirection, with values hard coded in it, and see that it works. If it does, it means something in your code either does some printing to the page, or that you don't build your target URL successfully for some reason.

Here's an example script:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // I added the require just to make sure nothing is being printed there
    // (an error for example)
    require_once('include/connect.php');
    require_once('include/util.php');

    header("Location: " . SOME_LOCATION);
    exit;
?>
```

and of course have some web page that prints OK when you redirect to it...

Comment: Hello, I've used wireshark. The HTTP parts Just have a standard GET /worknet/login.php HTTP/1.1 followed by a HTTP/1.1 200 OK. However when I try the script you posted I also get the white blank page and no redirection, which of course means somehow the inclusion of these two files is causing the problem?

Comment: it's easy to test if the require is causing the problem: just remove the require instructions and try the script again. If it works, then the problem is with the require.

Comment: When I remove it I still get the zero character before the doctype.

Comment: I didn't understand from your comment whether or not the redirection is being performed if you remove the require instructions..

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is is no problem with your code. Actually, ipage like hosting systems cause some issues. I have also used ipage hosting plans and faced same problems.

So buddy, try to find another hosting server which is better then these.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Ipage hosting, redirection does not work and server reports that headers have already been sent. Turns out the issue whas whitespace.

Make sure there is no whitespace nor any other character outside the `<?php code ?>` tags. Manually select and delete everything before the opening tag and after the closing tag in all files included prior to the redirection.